# Wordpress plugin and action hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm new in WP and I'm trying to create a new plugin and I'm having problems when adding new actions defined inside a class.
I guess the root problem is the way the code is executing and the init action hook but I cannot find my answer on internet and I want to know if there is an alternatve for this:

plugin.php file

```
...
require_once( PLUGIN_DIR . 'class.plugin.php' );
add_action( 'init', array( 'Plugin', 'init' ) );
...
```

class.plugin.php

```
class Plugin {

private static $instance = false;

public static function init() {

   if ( !self::$instance ) {
        self::$instance = true;
        self::init_hooks();           
    }
} 

private static function init_hooks() {
    add_action('init','foo1');
    add_filter('filter1', 'foo2');
}
public static function foo1(){
   ....
}

public static function foo2($var) {

  ....
}
```

Comment: And do you get any error? I do not know, will it works or not, but since your init method is static, try to call like this: `add_action( 'init', 'Plugin::init');` and for debug, `die('I am step here');` in the first line of your `init()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your action hook with

```
private static function init_hooks() {
   add_action('init',array( 'Plugin', 'foo1' ) );
   add_filter('filter1', array( 'Plugin', 'foo2' ));
```

Comment: If it has helped then can you please accept my answer?

Comment: I tried, but I don't have enough reputation. Could you please help me with this? In method 'foo1' I'm trying to set a cookie and I can't, probably it's due to the execution order, but I think it could be done.

Comment: public static function foo1(){
   setcookie('mycookie',$_GET['foo1'], time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
}
Thank you again!

Comment: Have you print or checked $_GET['foo1']? Do you get value of it?

Comment: Yeap, also if I use setcookie on init_hooks (and delete the line add_action(...)) it works. i.e:
private static function init_hooks() {
   //add_action('init',array( 'Plugin', 'foo1' ) );
   setcookie(...);
   add_filter('filter1', array( 'Plugin', 'foo2' ));